# UIWebView cannot load URL with three # symbols (hashtags) but Safari works fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiwebview, hashtag

I have this URL: http://m.10bet.com/#game_event#6404838#99
The numbers are always different but there are always three # hashtag symbols in it. UIWebView does not load it, but mobile Safari does, here is my code:

```
UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.10bet.com/#game_event#6404838#99"];
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

I know how to handle one # in URL (but not all three):

```
UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"#game_event" relativeToURL:@"http://m.10bet.com/"];
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fullURL]];
```

I also tried substituting # with %23 in URL but is does not work either.

What I have now as a workaround is that I call an URL Shortener which returns shortened URL and loads it into UIWebView, this works correctly but it's quite slow.

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the url? Have a look at `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`

Comment: Tried it `NSString * str = @"http://m.10bet.com/#game_event#6404838#99";
    NSString * encodedStr = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedStr];
    [_mainWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 NSString *str = @"http://m.10bet.com/";
 NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
 [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

On UIWebViewDelegate, add:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href = '#game_event#6404838#99'"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does work, I checked your solution and tried it before... no result.

Comment: thanks, this for swift
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(fromString: "window.location.href = '#game_event#6404838#99'")

Answer (score 2):

'#' is a special character, so need to encode it before loading into UIWebView. Mobile safari will do it automatically before start loading. So Replace the '#' with' %23' and try to load it in UIWebView.

Hope this will help you :)